# How can i prove Delta function property with derivative?

Tags: dirac-delta

How can i proof below delta function property?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta^{(n)}(t-a)dt=(-1)^{n}f^{(n)}(a)$$, where (n) denotes nth derivate.

Comment: What is your definition of the derivative of a distribution?

Comment: **Important point**, often not appreciated by students: **Any** time you're thinking seriously about math you need to have the **definitions** of **all** the terms in mind! Seem worth pointing out here, because that equation is nothing but the definition of $\delta^{(n)}$.

Comment: Or to be fair, it's the definition for $n=1$, and the case $n>1$ obviously follows (officially by induction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the formal definition of distributions and derivatives of such, just do integration by parts $n$ times. You will end up with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{(n)}(t) \, \delta(t-a) \, dt,$ which equals $f^{(n)}(a).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Lambda$ be a distribution and $\varphi$ be a test function. The very definition of the derivative of $\Lambda$ is
\begin{align}
\langle \Lambda',\varphi\rangle  = - \langle \Lambda,\varphi'\rangle 
\end{align}
This is because this matches the integration by part formula when $\Lambda$ is a true function. Apply this $n$ times and you get
\begin{align}
\langle \Lambda^{(n)},\varphi\rangle  = (-1)^n \langle \Lambda,\varphi^{(n)}\rangle 
\end{align}
Just replace $\Lambda$ by $\delta_a$ and you have your answer.

Notice $\langle \Lambda,\varphi\rangle $ stands for $\Lambda(\varphi)$ or $\int \Lambda\cdot \varphi$.